# How to resize webview contents including images to fit bounds horizontally

Tags: html, ios, swift, user-experience

I have a WKWebView on my app. If the web view contains a big image, it overflows the screen and users have to scroll horizontally.

How can I force the webview to clip the contents (resize images as needed) to fit the boundaries of the container?

Comment: you should be doing this in CSS and make sure that the viewport is set properly to the size of your webview

Comment: The webview doesn't have a static size, it fits to the size of the iphone. Is there a CSS command for that?

Comment: relative width, ie `width: 100%`. You just have to also set `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in your html. If your webview is 100% the width of the screen, this should work just fine. Essentially, you need to be constraining the image in CSS to be relative to the outside container

Comment: That worked - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mistahenry's comment worked for me:

relative width, ie `width: 100%`. You just have to also set `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in your html. If your webview is 100% the width of the screen, this should work just fine. Essentially, you need to be constraining the image in CSS to be relative to the outside container